Grabbing the value of a specific cell in an angular grid
I have a .ts file where I am defining the Row Data & Column Definitions.  The first column is named 'testfield1'.
The html is as follows:
<ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-quartz" style="height: 730px" [rowData]="rowData" [columnDefs]="colDefs"/>
I'm new to angular and am struggling with the basics here. How do I pass the value of column 'testfield1' for the currently selected row to a function within the .ts file please?
I am unsure as to how I obtain the row id using rowData[?].testfield1

You need to bind a function to the selectionChanged event
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-selection/

Thanks very much nll_ptr that has worked a treat.
